# CASE or IF then SELECT SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER Procedure _MySP (@oDate date)
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT * 
     FROM _table1
     WHERE oDate >= @oDate
END
```

I want to modified the query with something like:

```
IF @oDate <= '2017-06-01' 
THEN 
    SELECT * 
    FROM _table2 
ELSE  
    SELECT * 
    FROM _table1 
END
```

How can I achieve this? Please advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
alter Procedure _MySP (@oDate date)
as
begin
    If @oDate <= '2017-06-01'
        SELECT * FROM _table2
    else
        SELECT * FROM _table1
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alter Procedure _MySP (@oDate date)
as
begin
     select * from _table1 where @oDate => '2017-06-01'
     select * from _table2 where @oDate <= '2017-06-01'
end
```

Should do the trick. Hope you don't have equality case thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF @oDate <= '2017-06-01'
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM _table1
    --where--
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM _table2  
    --where--
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE _MySP (@oDate date)
BEGIN
IF (@oDate < = '2017-06-01')

BEGIN

   SELECT * FROM _table2 

END

ELSE

BEGIN

   SELECT * FROM _table1

END


END
```